# jQuery if two elements exists delete the first

Tags: jquery

I want to check if two elements exist. One has the #one the other #two.
And if both exists i want to remove #one.

If only #one exist do nothing.
If only #two exist do nothing.
If #one **and** #two exist delete #one.

Could someone help me to geht this thing working ?

```
if($("#one") AND $("#two")) {
$("#one").remove();
}
```

My little snippet does not wirk

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `&&` instead of `AND` and `length` to check if element exists. JQuery selector returns the object even the selector returns **No** element. So using .length will return zero when no element is return by selector and greater than zero when element(s) are returned by selector.

```
if($("#one").length && $("#two").length) {
   $("#one").remove();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
if ( $("#one, #two").length === 2 ) {
   $("#one").remove();
}
```